# Error : File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'

Tags: python

I am trying open a fitsfile from my system I open my directory I call a star but when I open this fitsfile I get a Error

```
Directory=r"C:/Users/sam/Desktop/23may.list", "r"    


    
star1=("EFOSC.2021-05-24T06:02:52.743.fits",)




   
hdu = fits.open (Directory + star1)

hdr = hdu[0].header 

dat = hdu[0].data 


zp = hdr['CRVAL1']

stw = hdr['CD1_1']
```

Error

```
----> 1 hdu = fits.open (Directory + star1)

OSError: File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'.
```

I do not know anymore what I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> print(Directory + star1)
('C:/Users/sam/Desktop/23may.list', 'r', 'EFOSC.2021-05-24T06:02:52.743.fits')
```

This doesn't look like anything `fits.open()` expects.  Construct file path properly and it will be just fine.

```
>>> fitsname = 'numpy/core/tests/data/recarray_from_file.fits'
>>> hdu = fits.open(fitsname)
>>> type(hdu[0].header)
<class 'astropy.io.fits.header.Header'>
```

Comment: Tnx a lot for your Answer